# Typescript declare type of defined strings or any string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I failed to find information on this elsewhere. I want to create a type that has both defined strings or allows any type of string to be used, but giving auto suggestion for the defined entries.

Right now if I add the `// | string` at the end, it sort of takes over, and doesn't give any auto suggestion.

```js
                                      // if I add this it stops suggestions
type DefinedLetters = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' // | string

const Letter: DefinedLetters  = '' // Should suggest A, B or C, but also allow D, E, F, etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this cool `LiteralUnion` type researching this for you, I think it works like a charm!

```
type LiteralUnion<T extends U, U = string> = T | (U & { });
type DefinedLetters = LiteralUnion<'A' | 'B' | 'C'>

const Letter: DefinedLetters  = "Cool!"
```

Comment: Neat! Seems that if you want you can get the same effect like: `type DefinedLetters = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | (string & { });`

Comment: @NicholasTower Indeed, that works too, the `LiteralUnion` just encapsulates that last string bit for re-use

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an enum and then in your usage, you can just specify your type as

```
let letter2: DefinedLetters | string;
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAIsBmBLEwAmAZYAXLwBOAzlAN4BQUFUAglALxQDkVDANOZQEJ2MevsUBhbgwENSAX1KkANtiiyc+AIwAuWAmRpMiwgG4Z2XHiXc4SFBkP4CAOiq6oAekdQAPAFooAewDWBnSb0DLgEWAwOzm7unlhE+HheeFIK8lZ4AExqZpqWOkQAPlCheMgA5voKRummGhbaRrb2Ti4e3n6V+NVBIWERLZ6+pEA)

```
enum DefinedLetters {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    C = 'C'
}

let letter1: DefinedLetters;
letter1 = DefinedLetters.A; // <- ok
letter1 = 'test'; // <-- ts error

let letter2: DefinedLetters | string;
letter2 = DefinedLetters.A; // <- ok
letter2 = 'test'; // <- ok
```

Not quite a `type` approach, but you get the same thing in this example.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but Nick's answer is more in line of what I want right now.